# opencart 1.5 paypal standard issue

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, opencart

So I followed the instructions per this link http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=documentation/documentation&path=32_35_60

but my paypal account is not being credited.

the error log(below) shows the ipn is moving back and forth. but no balances shows in paypal

2012-03-05 8:48:06 - PP_STANDARD :: IPN REQUEST: cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=1.00&invoice=13+-+tobechi+mlemchukwu&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&address_status=confirmed&item_number1=adfasf&payer_id=JKZVZAQKD5892&tax=0.00&address_street=11+walden+laurel+ct&payment_date=00%3A47%3A57+Mar+05%2C+2012+PST&payment_status=Pending&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=21207&mc_shipping=0.00&mc_handling=0.00&first_name=tobechi&address_country_code=US&address_name=tobechi+mlemchukwu¬ify_version=3.4&custom=fZ4%3D&payer_status=verified&address_country=United+States&num_cart_items=1&mc_handling1=0.00&address_city=baltimore&verify_sign=AomRS5l2W2xlt2An.GaSrAzpCl-NAT2IbPpLv.vUbRIXtRrM2gIGm3lq&payer_email=tobemlem%40yahoo.com&mc_shipping1=0.00&txn_id=3B916026RE773152B&payment_type=instant&last_name=mlemchukwu&address_state=MD&item_name1=test&receiver_email=medoror%40sneakerthirst.com&quantity1=1&pending_reason=unilateral&txn_type=cart&mc_gross_1=1.00&mc_currency=USD&residence_country=US&transaction_subject=fZ4%3D&payment_gross=1.00&ipn_track_id=9fdb34971a55c
2012-03-05 8:48:06 - PP_STANDARD :: IPN RESPONSE: VERIFIED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your payment_status is 'pending' and the pending reason is 'unilateral'.

You would not see the funds in PayPal.   Basically, PayPal is waiting to deliver the funds....

You need to check with paypal and make sure that **your** email address is confirmed, and that it is entered correct in opencart (e.g. check for typeos)

Comment: This was essentially the problem.  Now fixed. Thanks!